# Tensorflow Object Detection, error while generating tfrecord [TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int, long]

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tfrecord

When checking across different solutions available on the net, most people (including datitran) pointed out that it might be a missing class or a misspell of a class in the train csv file. Am not able to figure that out since the labelling is done using labelImg, it saves these classes as xml, the xml_to_csv.py converts this to a csv. Am not sure under what circumstance I could have had the opportunity to miss out or misspel any class incorrectly.

Here's the error am dealing with:

```
(OT) 
nisxxxxx@xxxxxxxx:~/Desktop/OD/models/research/object_detection$ 
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --
output_path=data/train.record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 192, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/nisxxxxx/Desktop/test_OD/OT/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 184, in main
tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 173, in create_tf_example
    'image/object/class/label': 
dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
File"/home/nishanth/Desktop/test_OD/models/research/object_detection/utils/dat
aset_util.py", line 26, in int64_list_feature
    return 
tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int, long
```

Has anyone been able to solve this problem?

Comment: closing this request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not sure how many classes you have used... after the final else try with  "return 0 instead of none"... example

```
if row_label == 'red':
    return 1
elif row_label == 'orange':
    return 2
elif row_label == 'blue':
    return 3
else:
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the label name whatever you labeling them during crop the image by labelImg tool.

```
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'raccon':
        return 1
    else:
        None
```

Instead of 'raccon' put label name for ex:- 'car'.